# Recuperando valores MultiSelectList MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Não estou sabendo como tratar os dados recebidos via `MultiSelectList`. Além disso, só consigo selecionar mais de uma opção na `View` se pressiono o CTRL. Existe uma forma do usuário conseguir clicar em mais de um valor sem necessariamente segurar essa tecla?

View `Create`

```
<div>
  Combos @Html.ListBox("Combos", new MultiSelectList(ViewData["Combos"] as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "id", "nome", Model.Combos.Select(x => x.id).AsEnumerable()))
</div>
```

Populando `MultiSelectList` no `Controller`

```
CombosAplicacao bdCombos;
bdCombos = CombosAplicacaoConstrutor.CombosAplicacaoEF();
ViewData["Combos"] = bdCombos.ListarTodos();
```

Em todo o resto da minha aplicação, trabalho com `SelectList`, pois tenho uma relação normalmente de 1 - n. Apenas no caso dos `Combos` que tenho uma relação de muitos para muitos.

---

No caso das `SelectList` trabalho da seguinte forma:

View `Create`

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sala", ViewData["Sala"] as SelectList)
```

Populando pelo `Controller`

```
SalaAplicacao bdSala;
bdSala = SalaAplicacaoConstrutor.SalaAplicacaoEF();
var listSala = new SelectList(bdSala.ListarTodos(), "ID", "Nome");
ViewData["Sala"] = listSala;
```

Recuperando e salvando no banco pelo `Controller`

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public PartialViewResult Create(CONGRESSO_Cursos cursos, FormCollection dados)
 {
     SalaAplicacao bdSala;
     bdSala = SalaAplicacaoConstrutor.SalaAplicacaoEF();
     cursos.CONGRESSO_Sala = bdSala.ListarPorId(dados["Sala"]);
     bdcursos.Salvar(cursos);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você recuperar o `dados["Combos"]`, vai recuperar todos que foram selecionados, então basta dar um split.

```
var combos = dados["Combos"].ToString().Split(',');
foreach(var combo in combos){
   //vai percorrer todos os combos selecionados.
}
```